# What is the correct syntax for the geometry object's "intersect" method in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, geometry, intersection

I'm building a script that utilizes the intersect method of the geometry class so that I can run an intersect analysis on individual polygons within a feature class. As stated [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000070000000),
 "intersect (other, dimension)" requires two parameters, but there is no explanation as to what kind of string they are expecting for "dimension". What should I pass to the method for that parameter? I can't find any documentation to tell me :(

Comment: Are you trying to intersect two features? What ArcGIS version are you using? also, do you plan to use a standalone script or run arcpy within ArcGIS?

Comment: I'm running ArcGIS 10.2. I'm using ArcPy within ArcGIS as a standalone script.

Comment: Ah... sorry my bad I'll remove the answer, [here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/10104)  is a good discussion where they talk about the use of `touches`, `crosses` or `disjoints` options for geometry analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to scroll down further on the [page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000070000000) in your post:

[image]

So, for example:

```
intersect = line_geom_object.intersect(other_line_geom_object, 1)
```

This will return a point geometry object wherever the two line features intersect.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I don't want to admit how many times I looked at that page trying to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the solution by looking up the corresponding method in ArcObjects. [This page](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#esriGeometryDimension.htm) defines which number codes should be used to define the Dimension of the features being analyzed. The method requires an integer in the second parameter. Here they are...

- 1 = Points
- 2 = Lines
- 4 = Polygons
- 5 = Surface Mesh
- 6 = 3D geometry
- -1 = Unspecified geometry